# Angualr2 - Exact project+packages , different computer - Errors only in one of them?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, npm

In my work I have :

- Windows 7
- Visual studio 2015 (typescript 2 installed)
- Resharper 2016.3.2
- npm version 3.10.10
- Node v 6.10.0

These are the global packages installed :

```
npm -g list --depth=0

+-- @angular/cli@1.0.0-rc.2
+-- typescript@2.2.1
+-- typings@2.1.0
`-- webpack@2.2.1
```

In my home I have Windows 10 , same software as described above. The global packages are also the same :

```
npm list -g --depth=0

+-- @angular/cli@1.0.0-rc.2
+-- typescript@2.2.1
+-- typings@2.1.0
`-- webpack@2.2.1
```

Project files - 100% the same :

[image]

Both projects run and build fine.

However  , I get errors only in my home computer  for `node_modules`:

[image]

And for my `spec.ts` files :

[image]

**Question**

I have same environment and same packages and same code. if so -  why then I get these errors and how can I fix them in my home computer?

NB

I already synced VS's settings file and also R#'s settings files , and still -  I get errors. Also both Visual studio is in "[**build+intellisense**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD7Ly.jpg)" mode.

Additional info :

[webpack.config.js](http://jsbin.com/zujasaqufa/edit?html,output)

[tsconfig.json](http://jsbin.com/fuxaxivugi/edit?html,output)

[angular-cli.json](http://jsbin.com/kakasaciru/1/edit?html,output)

[package.json](http://jsbin.com/memonunari/edit?html,output)

Comment: did you include any shims? It could be a browser compatibility issue.

Comment: @pixelbits I've added the configs at the bottom of the question. ( even if I didn't add shims , why in one place it does work and in the other it doesn't work? I use same softs in both environment).

Comment: Have you tried different browsers? is it an issue only on a specific browser?

Comment: It is not at the browser phase . It's in my visual studio

Comment: I've encountered an issue where the TypeScript extension for VS2015 didn't update properly. Have you checked that you have Update 3, and the same TypeScript extension version? i.e. goto VS >> help >> about, it should tell you the TypeScript version.

Comment: @pixelbits mmm this is [my work pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ziQj.png) and this is [in my home](https://i.imgur.com/gjsAsPb.jpg) : (thanks for helping BTW)

Comment: Right, if you scroll down that screen, it should show the TypeScript version.

Comment: @pixelbits I see that one has the 2'nd update and the other one has the 3'rd update.

Comment: Right, make sure you've updated to the same "Update", but also check the TypeScript version

Comment: Check this: http://imgur.com/a/pAYSt

Comment: @pixelbits [Yeah  i'm currently installing the culprit  VS to the 3'rd update](https://i.imgur.com/yujduql.jpg) Thanks

Comment: @pixelbits What can I say , you're the man.That was the problem . I had 1.8.6 typescript ( still after upgrading  VS to version 3. Plz post this as an answer so I can choose it .again - Thank you _very_ much

Comment: Can you please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814582/typescript-2-using-import-require-together) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that upgrade VS2015 to [Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs).

Also, I've encountered an issue in the past where the TypeScript extension for VS2015 doesn't update properly. For example, go to VS >> help >> about, it should tell you the TypeScript version.

Try installing the latest version for VS2015 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593), or go to Tools > Extensions and search for the TypeScript extension.