# Typescript 2 — using ES6 import & require?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, webpack

I have an exported `class` in my working Angular2 app using ES6 module:

```
//File = init.todos.ts

export class Init {
   load() {
      ...
    }
}
```

I'm importing this class from another component via :

```
//File = todo.service.ts

import { Init } from './init.todos'
```

It works as expected.

However if I change the loading mechanism to  commonjs  :

```
//File = init.todos.ts
export class Init {
    load() {
       ...
    }
}
 module.exports.Init = Init;
```

Requiring it:

```
//File = todo.service.ts
var  Init = require("./init.todos");
```

— I get those errors :

> ...myApp/src/app/todo.service.ts
>   (4,13): Cannot find name 'require'.)
>   ...myApp/src/app/todo.service.ts (12,14):
>   Property 'load' does not exist on type 'TodoService'.)

[image]

**Question:**

How can I also load  commonjs modules using `require` ?

Tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "module": "system",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2016",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

Here are the config files :

[tslint.json](http://jsbin.com/yuwicilocu/1/edit?html,output)

[tsconfig.json](http://jsbin.com/rezewukaxo/edit?html,output)

[package.json](http://jsbin.com/detaziqone/edit?html,output)

[angular-cli.json](http://jsbin.com/woyokemeci/edit?html,output)

[webpack.config.js](http://jsbin.com/botufokofa/edit?html,output)

Comment: This happens because you have `"module": "system"`. There's no require function in SystemJS.

Comment: @estus I've already [changed to 'commonjs' and still I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuwl5.png)

Comment: in tsconfig, change "module" to "commonjs" and keep the ES6 syntax e.g. `import { Init } from './init.todos'.

Comment: @BrunoGrieder Oh , so the imported module will have `module.exports` but I still should import it via es6 syntax ?

Comment: Yes. Typescript adopted ES6 style imports some time ago (1.5 or 1.7). If you use `const x = require('blah')`, you will be using NodeJS/CommonJS require and "lose" typing since `x`will be mapped to any. This may be useful to import JS librairies which are not typed though

Comment: @BrunoGrieder [mmm Still doesn't work , Did I miss something?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKhaZ.png)?

Comment: I see. In `init.todo.ts` use `export class Init { ...}`, do not touch modulle.exports. When transpiled to JS, the `module.exports` line will be generated **in the javascript file**. Typescript is exactly (~) like ES6 for modules

Comment: @BrunoGrieder but if a friend sends me a library which is a commonjs , he wouldn't have that export class . He would only have module.export . I don't always have control about the other libraries

Comment: That is true. You have two solutions: 1) There are type definitions available inside the library or on [DefintelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) or 2) use commonjs/nodeJS `require` i.e. `const blah = require('blah')` and you will not have types on `blah` (it will be typed to `any`)

Comment: I have tried to concatenate the whole discussion in answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since [version 1.5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2015/07/20/announcing-typescript-1-5/), Typescript has adopted the ES6 style of imports.

You can keep your code "as is"

```
//File = init.todos.ts

export class Init {
   load() {
      ...
    }
}

//File = todo.service.ts

import { Init } from './init.todos'
```

By moving the property `module` in `tsconfig.json` to `commonjs`, the transpiler will generate commonjs compatible javascript which will allow you to benefit from, and contribute to, the full nodeJS ecosystem.

```
"compileOptions": {
    ...
    "module": "commonjs"
    ...
}
```

If you wish to import an existing NodeJS module in your typescript code, a few things may happen

- the module ships with embedded Typescript Definition Files (there is a "typings" entry in "package.json"). In that case, import the module using the ES6 syntax and you are good to go (`import * as blah from 'blah'`). [immutable.js](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/package.json) is a good example of such a library
- the module does not ship with Definition files but there is one available on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), simply

  - run `npm install @types/blah` to get the definitions in your project
  - and import the module as usual: `import * as blah from 'blah'`
- the module does not have a definition file

  - you can craft one, simply add it to your project after naming it `blah.d.ts`. DefinitelyTyped has [a guide](http://definitelytyped.org/guides/creating.html) on this
  - you can decide to go without typings, simply use NodeJS require() `const blah = require('blah')`, and `blah` will have type `any` (which really means that `blah` opted out of typing)

(for sake of completeness, I could add the [allowJS compiler option](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/01/28/announcing-typescript-1-8-beta/) available since 1.8, but that is a whole subject in itself)

Comment: I'm sorry but did you mean in the second case : "_the module does not ship with Definition files but there is one available on DefinitelyTyped, simply_" - that I can import it via a _"regular require"_. right ? (I mean sure I can get it via ES6 import , but the whole point is that the d.ts allows TS to recognize the _require_ , no?)

Comment: TS does not "recognize the require". The point of having definition files is that the JS module can be used as if it were written in typescript and hence imported using typescript import syntax, which is the ES6 import syntax

Comment: Yeah , that's what I meant , it allows the TS compiler to recognize new `d.ts'ed` keywords. (correct me if I 'm wrong). but still I want to ask about the second case you mentioned. Even If I add `blah.d.ts` which my friend sent me with  his blah library ( commonjs) - Typescript only will be **muting errors** regarding the `require ('blah')` which I'll have in my code. right ? I mean I will have to have another module loader ( browserify/webpack) in order for the final JS to actual reference those required file. right?

Comment: Yes. You need a module bundler such as browserify or webpack. Using `require` or `allowJs` you may be able to avoid using one but you lose the benefit of typings

Comment: :-) ( finally i'm starting to get it.) - Ok if so - what difference does it make if I change the `module` in tsconfig ? I mean  - what does it have to do with TS  at first place ? From My testings - TS search es6 syntax and convert it. **[It doesn't care what you have in your code even if it's invalid](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=var%20g%20%3D%20ILove(()%20%3D%3E%20111)You%3B)**. Do you see where is my misunderstanding ? what does TS has to do with the tsconfig's module settings ? I mean it's up to webpack/browserify to "require" libraries (except es6 import built inTS).

Comment: It changes the way your javascript code is generated by the compiler.. and the bundlers bundle that code. It does not change the way you write typescript

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is ES6 compliant. Use ES6 module loading syntax within your TypeScript source files:

```
import  { SomeType } from './some.module';
```

When TypeScript compiles to regular JavaScript, you can target a module system of your choosing:

```
"compileOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs" (or system, umd, amd)
}
```

Whatever target module system you choose, you need to ensure that you include the necessary scripts and configuration to load the module.  i.e. SystemJS, RequireJS, etc.

As an exercise, try targeting different module loaders, and inspect the .js file - you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

the problem of your question actually is not the require(...) method.it is that you reference error Init.I think you want to [lazy load](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#optional-module-loading-and-other-advanced-loading-scenarios) modules via require.but you load class that contains an instance method `load`(it is not a class method,if you want you must declaring it as `static`).so you must create an instance before you use it.by default,require(...)  return any

```
declare function require(id: string): any;
```

if you want typescript infer type correctly you must declare require() return type,e.g:`let foo:typeof Foo = require('foo')`.I found that the `ts-jest` test pass when `module` is anything except `system` because it is lazy loading,not execute test definition immediately,so I'm sure the problem is not the module. here is my test code:

### Test

```
//for inferer type for typescript
//This leverages the reference-elision optimization,
//so that the module is only loaded when needed.
//so use InitClass as a type will skipped.
import {Init as InitClass} from  "./init.todos";

test("typescript dynamic load supports inferer types", () => {
    let Init: typeof InitClass = require("./init.todos").Init;

    let it = new Init();
    expect(it.load()).toEqual("bar");
});
```